# WCF: Array Parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, soap

I would like to define a C# WCF service that exposes an operation invoked by messages of a given format. An example of that message is given below. That format is defined by a client that I do not have control over. I control the service side only.

In summary, I have a WCF operation that is supposed to take an array as its only parameter. The array parameter is represented in the way the example message below shows. That parameter, however, is currently not correctly being de-serialized and ends up being empty on service side, although it appears correctly represented in the SOAP message from the client. How do I change my WCF service for the parameter to be correctly deserialized?

(I know there are a bunch of questions that seem very similar and lengthy MSDN articles on how to de-serialize collections and arrays in various formats, but for some reason I keep running into issues or I am simply not able to take the answer to a similar enough question and apply it to my scenario).

Here are some of the many things I have already tried:

- Varying the `OperationFormatStyle` and `OperationFormatUse` attributes on the `OperationContract`.
- Using and not using `ServiceKnownType` attributes for `string[]`.
- Using collections instead of array.
- Debugging into the WCF assemblies using .NET framework source stepping.
- Reading up on SOAP section 5 and 7 encodings.
- Adjusting the namespace parameters of the data contract members.
- Changing the names of the array elements in the data contract (`ItemNameAttribute`).

I think I have already come closer to something that works compared to the original code. Before, with `OperationFormatStyle.Rpc` and `OperationFormatUse.Encoded`, I simply received a `FaultException` stating that the request failed to de-serialize.

With the code below, at least I have no exception any more, but the de-serialized array on service side is empty.

Here is an example of the message I am receiving, which is supposed to invoke an operation with a single, string array type argument:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:iControl" xmlns:types="urn:iControl/encodedTypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://127.0.0.1/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">urn:iControl:GlobalLB/DataCenter</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <soap:Body soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <q1:get_object_status xmlns:q1="urn:iControl:GlobalLB/DataCenter">
      <data_centers href="#id1" />
    </q1:get_object_status>
    <soapenc:Array id="id1" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[3]">
      <Item>Datacenter 5d4afe7f-f4e0-4660-9ff1-9c1f8a15a1df</Item>
      <Item>Datacenter 70d88638-4622-46f1-8978-773898f57b0f</Item>
      <Item>Datacenter c8fc4b53-af74-4f71-b7a7-9102fbd684b6</Item>
    </soapenc:Array>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here is the operation contract I have eventually arrived at. The original one was generated with "svcutil" I believe, but I do not have the original WSDL files used back then anymore. I have full control over this part, though, so I can adjust code on service side to whatever works. There is a custom operation selector doing the dispatching, but that all seems to be working, because the implementing method on service side is invoked and when I simply substitute a string for the string array (while leaving everything else the same), the parameter ends up in the method correctly.

```
[GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[ServiceContract(Name = "IGlobalLB.DataCenterPortType", Namespace = "urn:iControl", ConfigurationName = "IGlobalLBDataCenterPortType"), DispatchByBodyElementBehavior]
public interface IGlobalLBDataCenterPortType
{
    // ...
    [OperationContract(Action = "urn:iControl:GlobalLB/DataCenter", ReplyAction = "ra")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(string[]))]
    get_object_statusResponse get_object_status(get_object_statusRequest request);
    // ...
}
```

Here is what the request data contract looks like. As said above, passing primitive parameters such as a plain string, instead of the string array (i.e. changing the type of `data_centers` from `string[]` to `string`), works as expected.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough()]
[GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "get_object_status", WrapperNamespace = "urn:iControl:GlobalLB/DataCenter",
    IsWrapped = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(string[]))]
public partial class get_object_statusRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
    public string[] data_centers;

    public get_object_statusRequest()
    {
    }

    public get_object_statusRequest(string[] data_centers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("XXX: " + String.Join(" ", data_centers));
        this.data_centers = data_centers;
    }
}
```

Here is the operation implementation:

```
public get_object_statusResponse get_object_status(get_object_statusRequest request)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Arguments: " + request.data_centers);
    Console.WriteLine("Datacenters:");
    foreach (var d in request.data_centers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    return new get_object_statusResponse();
}
```

The output is as follows, i.e. none of the array elements make it into the method. I would have expected the strings in the sample message to be contained in the array passed.

```
Arguments: System.String[]
Datacenters:
```

Comment: Can you please state your problem at hand in 1-2 sentences? I kind of get an idea what you want to achieve but I just can't make out your actual problem (maybe you forgot a NOT somewhere in those middle sections).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to restate the point of the question really briefly in the beginning. I hope it's better now.